# Replace sequence in list with a value in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, replace, sequence

I want to replace example two specific one-after-one going elements in a list with another element (elements).
For example - replace `["+", "="]` with `["+="]`:

Input:

```
[3, "blah", "+", "foo", "=", "+", "="]
```

Output:

```
[3, "blah", "+", "foo", "=", "+="]
```

Comment: Can you show what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've done a little wrapper for it using `zip` but I'm wondering if there's more short, elegant, Pythonic way (some good list comprehension or something else).

Comment: @R.O.S.S Can you add your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as I see these answers I think I'll post my solution. I've done a little wrapper function.

```
def replace(sequence, replacement, lst, expand=False):
    out = list(lst)
    for i, e in enumerate(lst):
        if e == sequence[0]:
            i1 = i
            f = 1
            for e1, e2 in zip(sequence, lst[i:]):
                if e1 != e2:
                    f = 0
                    break
                i1 += 1
            if f == 1:
                del out[i:i1]
                if expand:
                    for x in list(replacement):
                        out.insert(i, x)
                else:
                    out.insert(i, replacement)
    return out
```

Answer (score 2):

The following, though *very* inefficient for long lists this will work:

```
loop=[3, "blah", "+", "foo", "=", "+", "="]
out=[]
prevdone=False
for i in range(len(loop)):
    if loop[i]=="+" and loop[i+1]=="=":
        out.append("+=")
        prevdone=True
    elif not(prevdone):
        out.append(loop[i])
    else:
        prevdone=False
print(out)
```

It iterates through the list and checks if the current and following characters meet conditions. If they do, it will add `+=` and skip the next item.

I have considered using `"".join(list)` and `string.split("")` but that wouldn't (I don't think) work for multiple-character elements.

As for a general function, it could be modified as such:

```
def loopReplace(loopList, item1, item2):
    out=[]
    prevdone=False
    for i in range(len(loopList)):
        if loopList[i]==item1 and loopList[i+1]==item2:
            out.append(str(item1)+str(item2))
            prevdone=True
        elif not(prevdone):
            out.append(loopList[i])
        else:
            prevdone=False
    return out
```

Comment: I want the function to accept any sequence and any replacement.

Comment: @R.O.S.S Added that for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = [3, "blah", "+", "foo", "=", "+", "="]

for index, item in enumerate(list):
    if item =='+' and list[index +1]=='=':
        list[index] = "+="
        del list[index + 1]

print(list)
```

Comment: Your print statement should be `print(list)` as the original question pertained to Python 3.

Comment: It will raise exception that says that iterator changed its size during iteration.

Comment: @R.O.S.S Nope it wont. Have you tried it? Did you get the exception?

Comment: This will raise 'index out of range' if the last character is a "+" as it would still try to check if the next char is a "="